# add bootstrap button to to dynamically created bootstrap table

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, bootstrap-4

I have a dynamically created `bootstrap` `html table` from a `database`.
The is is a template of the table design I'm using: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8G2Q

this is the button im trying to add to the "del" columns: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ (Danger)

```
    void main()
    {


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection conn = Connect.main();
        command = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.Suppliers", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.Columns.Remove("country");
        dt.Columns.Remove("state");
        dt.Columns.Remove("street_name");
        dt.Columns.Remove("street_number");

        dt.Columns.Remove("rep_first_name");
        dt.Columns.Remove("rep_last_name");
        dt.Columns.Remove("rep_contact_number");
        dt.Columns.Remove("rep_email");




        String  html = ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt);
        String core;// = ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt);
        conn.Close();





String formated = String.Format(@"
<div class='container'>
    <div class='panel panel-primary filterable'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h3 class='panel-title'>Suppliers</h3>

        </div>
        <table class='table' >
            <thead>
                <tr class='filters'>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='#'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Name'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Phone # 1'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Phone # 2'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Email 1'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Email 2'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Website'></th>
                    <th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Active'></th>
<th><input type = 'text' class='form-control' placeholder='Del'></th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {0}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


", html);

        myDiv.InnerHtml = formated;


    }
```

---

```
public string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
{
        string html ="";// = "<table>";
        /*
    //add header row
    html = "<tr>";
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        html += "<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";*/
    //add rows
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";


        ///////////////////////////////////////// this is testing code for the button creation
            // html += "<td>" + "<input type='submit' name='name' value='Save' runat='server' />" + "<td>";
            HtmlButton btn = new HtmlButton();
            btn.ID = "myID";
            btn.Attributes["class"] = "mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored";

            btn.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"material-icons\">add</i>";


            html += "<td>" + btn + "<td>";
         /////////////////////////////////////////
         ///
            html += "</tr>";
    }
  //  html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

I cant figure out how to add this particular type of button to the table that i'm making. Could someone point me in the right direction? I've been experimenting with different types of buttons though i really want the one that looks like the one from that link provided above.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of using the HtmlButton object?

This requires rendering in the pipeline else it will output this

```
<td>System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton<td>
```

It you don't need to bind it, just use a basic string (which is what you are returning from the method anyway)

```
 html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='material-icons'>add</i></button>";
```